# send image url to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this page i want to send image uploaded URL to another php page

[image: image for the page]

i've used this code to display the image in box.
javascript:

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
var image = document.getElementById('output');
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

HTML:

```
<label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;" ><br>
<img id="output" width="175" height="120" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send it like that when redirecting to your_page :`<?php header('Location:yourPage?image=image_url'); ?>`

and you can get it in your destination page like that : `<?php $image = _GET['image'] ?>`

Comment: I've tried this solution but it doesn't work because I want it to redirect to the another page on export button click not when upload the image

Comment: Yes, You are redirecting using javascript or php ?